# Change color/appearance of ONE item in the overflow menu

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

Recently I've been asked to add a special overflow menu item which has a different color or background than other menu items -- just that one item.

I already have a custom theme for the appearance of my overflow menu, so I do not need information on how to use a theme to style all my menu items.  I just need to change the appearance of one.

Is this possible, and how?

Bonus points for solutions working on ActionBarSherlock, but really, I'll take anything.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but the Menu Resource documentation says that a menu `<item>` can have an `android:actionLayout` attribute.

So, you should be able to specify a custom layout for your one menu item, and use a style for that one layout that's different from the overall theme.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I said above, this is in the *overflow* menu, where only menu titles are displayed regardless if the `actionLayout` is specified.  In my case, to guarantee it is in the overflow, I am specifying `android:showAsAction="never"`.